# Browser extension replaces with only 1img

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My extension is supposed to replace all images on a page with gifs comming from a single source(generates different gif on every click).But when iterating over page images replaces them all with the same gif.I can see the browser loads it only once and replaces it everywhere,how do I avoid that?

```
  console.log("Fear me!");
let imgs=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(elt of imgs){
    elt.src='https://api.thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=gif';
}
```

Comment: Do you run this for loop on click?

Comment: Sounds like the browser is caching the response which probably means this is what thecatapi tells the browser to do in its response as I see the same in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution commonly used is to add a unique timestamp at the end of the URL so that it's not cached. Here I'll ask for timestamp only once and just add +1 for each image.

(forgive inline obtrusive JS function in HTML, it's just for the example)

```js
function refresh1(){
    let imgs=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for(elt of imgs){
        elt.src='https://api.thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=gif';
    }
}

function refresh2(){
    let imgs=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    let time=(new Date()).getTime();
    for(elt of imgs){
        elt.src='https://api.thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=gif&t=' + time;
        time++;
    }
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="refresh1()">without timestamp</button>
<button onclick="refresh2()">with timestamp</button><br>
<img src=""/>
<img src=""/>
```

Comment: TNX Kad, you rock!